# What am i doing wrong with this in asp.net-mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hyperlink, resources

I gave this in my `site.master`

`<li><%= Html.ActionLink("Material", "Index", "Material")%></li>`

But my link doesnt seem to get my `material` controller `Index` method... I have this in my global asax file,

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  
             );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                            
                new { controller = "Material", action = "Index", id = "" }  
            );

        }
```

My controller:

```
public class MaterialController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Material/
    Material material = new Material();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var materials = material.FindAllMaterials();
        return View();
    }
 }
```

What am i doing wrong.... When i click the link i get 
`The resource cannot be found.` error.. Any suggestion...

Comment: Try to remove one of the routes. I'm surprised the application even ran since you have the same name for two different routes. The second route definition will never be used since any link that fills the second one will be filled in the first one.

Comment: @Baddie how about changing the name for the route?

Comment: Remove the last route, it will `never` be mapped to since there is a previous route exactly like it. Is there a reason you have both of them? You only need one of them to map to the default action/controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dump question -> make sure you've saved/compiled. What hints that u didn't do this, is that u have two routes with the same name (aka. Default). Compiler should error.

Secondly, try to manually goto that resource. Ie, goto http://localhost:/materials/index and see if that works. Of course, replace the localhost with whatever is the dev url of your site. If that works.. continue.

Thirdly, hover the mouse over the html anchor (aka. the a href) and see what is displayed in the browsers 'status' bar. It should list the resource url which that anchor will redirect you to. Does it say 'http://localhost:/materials/index' ??

basically, the code looks ok for the HTML.ActionLink .. but there's a few other possible things that have happened to screw this up.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "But my link doesn't seem to get my material controller"? What is the link it generates?

Download the routing debugger from here: 
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Register it and see what route it is using when you type in the url manually.

Comment: @Raj ya i did type in the url manually it gave me the error `Resource not found`